# Adding "Boot to Windows 10" in Grub (Other Solutions Suck)

Tags: grub2, windows, mint

First I'll start with a list of things I tried.

- update grub (sudo update-grub)
- EasyBCD on Windows 10 (Doesn't allow Linux Entries)
- Disabled hibernation (Windows 10)
- Disabled quick startup (Windows 10)
- Ran the grub repair tool for Linux
- Tried to manually install the entry(sudo grub-install /dev/sda3)

Every other post I have seen mentions these in one capacity or another.  What is my next step if none of these have worked?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to boot with Boot-Repair live cd, and select the option

"Restore MBR" under Advanced Options?
[Boot-Repair Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2U7y.png)

Here you can get the 32/64bit version of Boot-Repair ISO: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

Comment: No I have not.  Will try this now.

Comment: Ok, let me know ;)

Comment: That is not an option in my Boot Repair. [Image](http://imgur.com/a/MUK3O)

Comment: Sorry for the waiting! Installing few things.  Check your partitions please and post :

Comment: 'sudo fdisk -l'

Comment: so do you solved the question?